# $S=\{x\in l_2: \sum {x_i\over n}=0\}$ we need to find int S

Tags: functional-analysis

we consider the hilbert space $l_2$ under the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum x_i y_i$, consider the set $S=\{x\in l_2: \sum {x_i\over  n}=0\}$

I need to know the number of interior points of $S$. I did like this

$f:l_2\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\sum {x_i\over  n}$ is a linear functional and kernel or inverse image of closed set $0$ is $S$ will be a closed subset of $l_2$ which is nowhere dense so $\mathrm{int} S=\varnothing$ am I right?

Comment: I changed $\phi$ to $\varnothing$.  $\phi$ is the Greek letter, distinct from the common symbols $\varnothing$ or $\emptyset$ used to denote the empty set.

Comment: @JonasMeyer is there any shorter latex command for empty set?

Comment: Senore: `\varnothing` and `\emptyset` are all I know, but I've never tried to find something shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Proper subspaces have empty interior (even if they are not closed), because an open ball would generate the whole space.

Or, directly, if $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ is in $S$, then $(x_1+t,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ is not when $t\neq 0$, no matter how small $t$ is.